# Selecting rows of attributed relationship class (intermediate table) using relate table function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, relationship-class, relates, sorting

I have 2 classes:

Owners

Properties

And 1 relation class (M-N) attributted

In my ArcMAP (10.3.1) the intermediate table doesn't appear automatically (The table of relationed class appear). If I opening a table of intermediate table and running the function "relate table" again, occurs a error in this table:

[image]

And nothing is selected in relation table... (but in the relationed class the behavior is normal).

I found this old tutorial that it works well

"http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/EditingRelationships_4.htm"

In this link, in segment 4/5, is showing how to edit a intermediate table, using a function relate table.

I guess this a bug of new versions. Can Anyono test this too?

Comment: Rather than just linking to a very old tutorial can you list the precise steps that you performed leading up to this error, please?